# Distributing business app on App Store that requires an account

Tags: iphone, deployment

Our business is currently looking at developing iPhone versions of applications we build for our clients. The apps are currently used internally within these businesses and are not (currently) web-facing.

A stumbling block seems to be deployment - requiring all of our clients to sign up for the iPhone enterprise programme won't work, as this is a big ask for companies who outsource their IT infrastructure (e.g. this simple task will probably end up costing lots of time and money and become a project in itself!).

I've been doing some research and haven't found a straight answer so far - is Apple happy to distribute applications which require logins to existing (paid for, business) services? I guess my main examples in this case would be spotify (not business but requires paid account) or Salesforce.com (again, requires paid account).

Comment: Would it be any different than the Netflix app requiring a paid Netflix account?

Comment: I guess the difference is these guys have a service available to the wider public (or their service is available, in the case of salesforce) on the web, whereas we sell B2B. May not be a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are *many* examples of it being allowed (Spotify, Twitter and Facebook clients, etc.), here's one which Apple rejected for requiring registration:

http://readitlaterlist.com/blog/2010/08/version-2-2-rejected-new-rejection-reason-from-apple-may-have-major-implications/

However many people on Hacker News considered this to be a mistake on the reviewer's part, rather than something in Apple's guidelines:

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1626034

Answer (score 1):

> Is Apple happy to distribute applications which require logins to existing (paid for, business) services?

Yes, there are very many examples:

- [Amazon.co.uk](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/amazon-mobile-uk/id335187483?mt=8) and all the other shopping apps might be examples
- [Streetcar](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/streetcar/id335331332?mt=8)
- [iDisk](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobileme-idisk/id320654497?mt=8) (by Apple)
- [Find My iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8) (by Apple)
- [Sky+](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sky/id301250225?mt=8)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Sklivvz is right, the only gotcha is they will already need a login to your service. If you let them create and pay for an account inside the app, you will have to use Apple's in app purchase and Apple gets 30%.

cf App Review Guidelines, section 11 (Purchasing).

Alternatively, you can launch Mobile Safari from the App, and after registering you can pass their login details back to the app using a custom URL handler (eg. myappid://somestring/) here is an explanation of custom URL schemes http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html